# changing file names, how to?

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-autoform

I've created some forms following this approach:

iron g:template cars/create_car

and the following files were created:

```
create_car.css
create_car.html
create_car.js
```

Easy question - if I want to change the name of the files where else do I have to update to keep my changes in sync with the rest of the application?

Thank you!

Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be out of sync by changing file's name.

The only things which would change is the file load order, according to the documentation:

> 1. HTML template files are always loaded before everything else.
> 2. Files beginning with main. are loaded last
> 3. Files inside any lib/ directory are loaded next
> 4. Files with deeper paths are loaded next
> 5. Files are then loaded in alphabetical order of the entire path

On your case It's wouldn't probably cause any issue, feel free to test.